# Integral in Prime counting function

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

I've come across on another stack exchange question somewhere that gave a definition for the integral that appears in Riemann's prime counting formula.  The integral in question is $$\int_{x^{1/n}}^\infty\frac{1}{t(t^2-1)\ln(t)}dt$$ and if I recall, it was defined in terms of the Riemann function $R(x)$ and/or $\mu(x)$.  Could someone help give the definition of this integral?

Comment: hints : $\frac{1}{1-t^{-2}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty t^{-2k}$, if $F(s) = \int_a^\infty t^{-s} \frac{f(t)}{\ln t} dt$ then $F'(s) = -\int_a^\infty t^{-s} f(t) dt$ and [Riemann's explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Riemann.27s_explicit_formula) which is obtained from the inverse Mellin transform / residue theorem applied to $-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{s\zeta(s)} = \int_1^\infty \psi_0(x) x^{-s-1} dx$ where $\psi_0(x) = \sum_{p^k < x} \ln p$ (for detailed proofs type "Riemann explicit formula" on google)